# Are humans naturally good at finding patterns or is it a trained ability?

Tags: epistemology, knowledge

When I once looked at the triangle illusion, I wondered why I was seeing a triangle in the middle of the screen, even though it was white space. This lead me to wonder why do humans find patterns in the universe whether they exist or not?Are we naturally good at finding these patterns or is it a trained ability?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. Could you clarify how this is a philosophical question and not one for [cogsci.se]?

Comment: I agree, this is probably a cognitive science question.  Some insight may come from how babies look at patterns.  I've shown my child gestalt patterns in the first few weeks of life, and there was a noticeable difference in attention level in some of them.

Comment: This is cognitive science, and the answer is neither. Two many heterogenous mental activities fall under "finding patterns" for any particular "ability", inborn or trained, to account for them. "*Peirce’s suggestion that abduction requires a special instinct for
guessing right is not well supported by current neuropsychological findings*", see Thagard, http://cogsci.uwaterloo.ca/Articles/Thagard.brains-models.2010.pdf

Comment: @Conifold I disagree, see my answer.

Comment: @Alexander I think, AI are specialized to recognize specific types of patterns, reflecting perhaps different brain functions, but not an omnivorous "ability". I agree that Locke, Kant, Peirce, etc., stood at the origins of cognitive psychology, but things change, natural philosophy became physics. Even Fodor's and Chomsky's suggestions, to the extent that they are "theories" or "hypotheses", fall under cognitive psychology/linguistics (and they did not fare well there).

Comment: @Conifold there's a lot of overlap between Phil. mind and cognitive science. The real question is: Should questions pertaining to pre-paradigm sciences get systematically sent to their designated SE the way questions from normal phase sciences do, or can they still remain here, given that they have 'philosophical' content?

Comment: @Alexander It is hard to devise a general rule, I suppose parts of them are proto and parts "normal". For me it usually turns on the balance of a question. For this one I am afraid of multiple "common sense" goings about nature vs. nurture, as in other "festering threads", and the question itself is phrased presupposing a "common sense" stereotype, which is better dispelled on CogSci SE. I have nothing against your answer specifically.

Answer (score 0):

At one level, your question is a trick question:

> Are we naturally good at finding these patterns or is it a trained ability?

Pattern Recognition *is* the ability to learn or train a system in detecting patterns. Within the field of AI, the terms "[Pattern Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition)" and "[Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning)" are used (almost) interchangeably. Sometimes Pattern Recognition is considered a subset of Machine learning, other times they are considered to be the same.

So to answer your question: Pattern recognition isn't a trained ability, so much
as it is itself the ability to learn and train - and we are naturally very good at this ability, because we are good at learning.

At a second level your question is more interesting and falls within longstanding debate in philosophy of mind of whether we have innate knowledge or whether we start with a blank slate and learn everything from scratch. See [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/innateness-history/), [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/innateness-cognition/) and [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rationalism-empiricism/#3) for more information and references.

The two opposing postions are:

- Nativism: We have innate knowledge (obtained from past lives, from Plato's world of forms, pre-programmed into us by evolution, etc....there are different explanations for where it came from). In this view, we *are not* simply pattern recognition devices, but have some other advanced processing abilities such as language, mathematics, etc...
- Empiricism: We do not have any innate knowledge. Instead we learn everything from our experience with the world through the sense/empirical data we accumulate. This view was most famously described by [Locke's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Locke) concept of [Tabula Rasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_rasa) (blank slate). In this view, everything we do comes down to advanced levels of pattern recognition without any other forms of processing of knowledge.

Historically, the second empirical view is considered to have "won" the battle, [see here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/innateness-history/#TemTriAntNat), but the nativists view point was brought back with Chomsky's [theory of universal grammar](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/innateness-cognition/#ChoRevLin), and more recently with Jerry Fodor's [language of thought hypothesis](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/language-thought/).